# How to create an infinite wrapping orbiting background in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

So I have been searching for a way to have a background orbit around a centerpoint. I came across the greensock blitmask that does an amazing job of wrapping the bitmap data to do infinte scrolling effects. However, I can't figure out a way to use this blitmask to rotate the bitmap data and still have the wrapping effect. Below is a link to my SWF.

The image that moves is the one that I wish to wrap and have the infinite scrolling effect. The problem is dealing with repositioning after the image has moved off the screen since it has been rotated.

**EDIT**: I totally forgot about this issue and decided put it on the backburner for my game since it was taking too long to figure. I recently returned to this concept because I had an idea to make it work. Below is a link to the .SWF that shows what I was trying to accomplish. Though this example works, I dont feel its the best solution.

"WASD" control movement

### [Orbiting Background](http://shawn-freeman.com/assets/orbitingbkgd.swf)

I used some trigonometry to calculate the distance a star is from the player. If that star is beyond that distance, reposition it using it's angle * -1. The code for this is under the link.

```
var travelVal:Number = 0;
var turnVal:Number = 0;
var currentChild:DisplayObject;
var currentStar:Star;
var childIndex:int = 0;
var angle:Number = 0;
var distance:Number = 0;

if (controller.isKeyDown(Keyboard.A))
        {
            turnVal += TURN_SPEED;
        }

        if (controller.isKeyDown(Keyboard.D))
        {
            turnVal -= TURN_SPEED;
        }

        if (controller.isKeyDown(Keyboard.W))
        {
            travelVal += PLAYER_SPEED;
        }

        if (controller.isKeyDown(Keyboard.S))
        {
            travelVal -= PLAYER_SPEED
        }

        for (childIndex = 0; childIndex < numChildren; childIndex++)
        {
            currentChild = getChildAt(childIndex);

            //if (currentChild != player && currentChild != debugOutput && currentChild != blackBkgd)
            if(currentChild is Star)
            {
                currentStar = currentChild as Star;

                //move this child based on the travel value
                currentChild.y += travelVal * currentStar.speed;

                //calculate the orbiting
                distance = Math2.distanceBetweenObjects(player, currentChild);
                angle = Math.atan2(currentChild.y - player.y, currentChild.x - player.x);

                if (distance > STAGE_WIDTH ) angle = angle * -1; 
                //get orginal angle in radians
                //angle = Math.atan2(currentChild.y - player.y , currentChild.x - player.x);
                angle = Math2.radiansToDegress(angle);
                angle += turnVal;
                //currentStar.rotation = angle;

                angle = Math2.degreesToRadians(angle);

                currentChild.x = player.x + (distance * Math.cos(angle));
                currentChild.y = player.y + (distance * Math.sin(angle));
            }
        }
```

Comment: A major disadvantage of blitting is that you can't rotate the result, you have to rotate the entire canvas (bitmap) which will of course present problems of its own.

Comment: how would I go about rotating bitmap data? From the looks of it, the only way of control the image is by looping through the individual pixels and adjusting their location. But i havent had the the pleasure of messing with bitmap data yet.

Comment: I updated the main post with a demonstration of what I was talking about. I suggest actually downloading the swf and running it

Answer (score 1):

In order to rotate around a certain centerpoint, you first translate by (-centerpoint.x,-centerpoint.y), then rotate around (0,0) and then translate back by (centerpoint.x,centerpoint.y).